# Will Delphi XE4 install on Windows 10 and will the apps created with XE4 run on Windows 10?

Tags: delphi

I have Delphi XE4 that I have never used and I have an upcoming project that I need to create an app that will need to run on Windows 10 64bit. I have several questions:

1 - Will XE4 install and work correctly on Windows 10?

2 - Will the apps created with XE4 run on Windows 10, 32bit or 64bit apps?

3 - Are there other issues I should be aware of regarding XE4 and Windows 10?

Thanks,
TD

Answer (score 2):

> 1 - Will XE4 install and work correctly on Windows 10?

Yes.

> 2 - Will the apps created with XE4 run on Windows 10, 32bit or 64bit apps?

Yes.

> 3 - Are there other issues I should be aware of regarding XE4 and Windows 10?

XE4 does not have Windows per-monitor High DPI support built in. This can be worked around, but depending on your requirements it may require substantial changes, including modifications of VCL Form and Screen classes.

More precisely, if application has to run only in single monitor environments or only in multiple monitor environments where all monitors have same DPI settings then there are no problems and simple entry in application manifest will do.

However, this quick hack cannot be used if application has to run in multiple monitor setups where each monitor can have different DPI settings. In that case application will either run in compatibility mode which will result in blurry forms on High DPI monitors, or changes to the VCL are required to avoid blurriness.

Comment: The users will just be using a standard workstation so do you for see any issues with that setup?

Comment: @DLee DPI settings can be freely changed in Windows by the user.

Comment: @DLee Most likely you will have no problems in such setup.

Comment: Thank you for answering!